# Oracle APEX - switching Region Display Selector regions from a link item

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex21.2

I have a couple of classic report columns that are links and a region display selector with a couple of regions under it. How can I switch between RDS regions dynamically when a corresponding column link is clicked?

I tried setting link type to URL and set it to

```
apex.region("RDS").widget().aTabs("getTabs")["#MY_TAB_STATIC_ID"].makeActive();
```

But that did not work - APEX tried to go to a different page.

Comment: Do you want to click somewhere in the page and then change the active tab in the RDS in that same page ? Or do you want to click a link that goes to another page and sets an active tab there ?

Comment: I want to click a link item on the page and change the active tab on the same page

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option. I didn't use page items but you'll probably be able to reuse the logic:

- Create 2 regions, give them static id rdsregion-1 and rdsregion-2
- Create a display selector
- Create a static report with the following sql:

```
select EMPNO,
       ENAME,
       JOB,
       MGR,
       HIREDATE,
       SAL,
       COMM,
       DEPTNO , 
       CASE WHEN SAL > 2500 THEN '<div class="setrds1">set rds 1</div>' ELSE '<div class="setrds2">set rds 2</div>' END as rds
  from EMP
```

- Create a dynamic action named "Set RDS1"

  - Event: Click
  - Selection Type: jQuery Selector
  - jQuery Selector: .setrds1
- add a true action to DA "Set RDS1" o

  - Action "Execute Javascript Code"
  - Javascript code:

```
$('#rdsregion-1_tab a').trigger("click");
```

- Create a similar dynamic action for RDS2.

Note that both snippets work:

```
$('a[href="#rdsregion-1"]').trigger("click");
```

and

```
$('#rdsregion-1_tab a').trigger("click");
```

Comment: my link is a column in a classic reports, I cannot set a dynamic action for it

Comment: Use a class instead of an id in the report. In the DA us e “.setrds1” as jquery selector. That should work in a classic report.

Comment: Changed my answer to work with classic report column. Works fine for me.